# Wizard, click in tab and redirect to it

Tags: primefaces, wizard

I'm working with a wizard in primefaces, the behavior is the regular one, a few tabs, click next to go next, click back to go back, onflowproces, etc. The problem is that in certain cases you can enter to the page in read-only mode, and as in that case is unnecessary to pass every single step to reach a certain step, I want to find the way to click in the tab and redirect.

The wizard consists in 8 tabs, every single tab could be accessed adding the id of the tab in the url param, the only thing I have to do is find a way to click the tab and redirect to the url of the tab.

Is there a way to achieve this? thanks!

Comment: PF version? If you bind `step="#{bean.mystep}`, then you can modify server-side the value and updating the wizard you go straight to that step.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Im working with primefaces 6.2. If I didnt understand you wrong, the thing you say I already have it, the thing I need is click the tab and redirect to it. The part im missing is the one that "convert" the tab in a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the name of the wizard as a link to their tab I override WizardRenderer like this:

```
    package myImportantPackage;  
 
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;

    import org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab;
    import org.primefaces.component.wizard.Wizard;
 
  
    public class WizardRenderer extends org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer {
             
            @Override
            protected void encodeStepStatus(FacesContext context, Wizard wizard) throws IOException {
                ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
                String currentStep = wizard.getStep();
                boolean currentFound = false;
         
                writer.startElement("ul", null);
                writer.writeAttribute("class", Wizard.STEP_STATUS_CLASS + " wizard-panels", null);
                int i = 0;
                for(UIComponent child : wizard.getChildren()) {
                    if(child instanceof Tab && child.isRendered()) {
                        Tab tab = (Tab) child;
                        boolean active = (!currentFound) && (currentStep == null || tab.getId().equals(currentStep));
                        String titleStyleClass = active ? Wizard.ACTIVE_STEP_CLASS : Wizard.STEP_CLASS;
                        if(tab.getTitleStyleClass() != null) {
                            titleStyleClass = titleStyleClass + " " + tab.getTitleStyleClass();
                        }
                         
                        if(active) {
                            currentFound = true;
                        }
         
                        writer.startElement("li", null);
                        writer.writeAttribute("class", titleStyleClass, null);
                        if(tab.getTitleStyle() != null) writer.writeAttribute("style", tab.getTitleStyle(), null);
                         
                        writer.startElement("a", null);
                        final String wiz = wizard.resolveWidgetVar();
                        writer.writeAttribute("href", "javascript:PF('"+wiz+"').loadStep(PF('"+wiz+"').cfg.steps["+i+"], false)", null);
                        if (tab.getTitletip() != null) writer.writeAttribute("title", tab.getTitletip(), null);
                        writer.write(tab.getTitle());
                        writer.endElement("a");
                         
                        writer.endElement("li");
                        i++;
                    }
                }
         
                writer.endElement("ul");
            }    
        }
```

And registered it in `faces-config.xml`, like this

```
<renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.WizardRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>myImportantPackage.WizardRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

Comment: Hey, you are amazing, its working!! Thank you so much!